# mef export based on metadata

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mef

I am trying to export a module based on its metadata.
the `compositioncontainer`contains two parts in its catalogue

```
[1] = {Modules.ProjectModule}
[0] = {Modules.DocumentsModule}
```

but the `GetExportedValues` returns nothing.

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IModule))]
private List<Lazy<IModule, IModuleInfo>> specific_modules { get; set; }
public ShellViewModel()
{
    DirectoryCatalog catalaog = new DirectoryCatalog(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Modules", "*.*");
    CompositionContainer compositioncontainer = new CompositionContainer(catalaog);
    specific_modules = compositioncontainer.GetExportedValues<Lazy<IModule, IModuleInfo>>().ToList();
    Documents = specific_modules.FirstOrDefault<Lazy<IModule, IModuleInfo>>().Metadata.DisplayName;
}

public interface IModuleInfo
{
    string DisplayName { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    string Version { get; }
}

public interface IModule
{
    string Name { get; }
}

namespace Modules
{
    [Export(typeof(IModule))]
    [ExportMetadata("DisplayName", "Documents")]
    [ExportMetadata("Description", "gérer les docs")]
    [ExportMetadata("Version", "2.1")]

    public class DocumentsModule : IModule
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "Documents";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
 specific_modules = compositioncontainer.GetExportedValues<Lazy<IModule, IModuleInfo>>().ToList();
```

You need to specify the type of the contract of the modules you want to get. In your case, you would have to do this:

```
var listOfModules = compositioncontainer.GetExportedValues<IModule>().ToList();
```

`specific_module` could then be filled/formed by using the `Select` LINQ method.

Sources:

- [T - The type of the exported object to return. The contract name is also derived from this type parameter.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986386(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [This question, although different problem contains the solution for your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4602625/937093)